# Ubuntu 16.04 software app not working, snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request

Tags: software-installation, gnome-software, slack

[image: Ubuntu App store Error]

```
snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request
```

When I try to install any application from the Ubuntu Software app, it shows an error. I think the last update caused it. Before that update it was working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `snapd return status code 400 : Bad Request` error may be caused because slack must be installed from the terminal with the `--classic` confinement option with this command:

```
sudo snap install slack --classic
```

A snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, however the default snap package installation installs the snap package without full access to the system so the installation of slack in the Ubuntu Software app failed.

To show information about the options required to properly install slack run this command:

```
snap info slack
```