# Snap "store.RevisionNotAvailable" Error

Tags: snap, microk8s

I was trying to install microk8s on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS by executing this command:

```
sudo snap install microk8s -- classic
```

However I got this error:

```
error: store.RevisionNotAvailable with 2 snaps
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS app store not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008368/ubuntu-16-04-lts-app-store-not-working)

Comment: @karel Thanks for the link. It surely helped me understand the --classic confinement option :)

Comment: If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the space between the dash and "classic" ...

The correct command is:

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
```